# checkbox value not get -> Notice: Undefined index: name1 in C:\wamp\www\crud_exer1\content.php on line 27

Tags: php, post, checkbox

I'm trying to do multiple deletion with checkboxes.. But as a test, I tried to get the values of the first two checkboxes but it's not working.. I did:

```
<td> <input type="checkbox"  name=" <?php echo $name[$pos]; ?> " value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" /> </td>
```

to display records first when the page loads then at the top, I did the following to print the name of the first 2 checkboxes as well as print the value of the 1st checkbox:

```
elseif(isset($_POST["delete"])){
        echo $name[0];
        echo $name[1];
        $value_of_box =  $_POST["$name[0]"];
        echo $value_of_box;
    }
```

but only the name of the checkboxes are recognized since it prints

> name1name2

but I'm getting this error: "

> Notice: Undefined index: name1 in C:\wamp\www\crud_exer1\content.php
>   on line 27

" when it comes to printing the value of the checkbox.. I thought that if it recognized the name of the box, it should also recognized the value, right?
WHAT'S WRONG WITH THIS?

Comment: Did you tick the `checkbox` before submitting the form ?

Comment: what do you mean by "tick" exactly? if you mean like declare it, i did.. it even prints the name of the checbox.. but not the value..

Comment: Oh! You mean a tick mark? Yeah, I did.. I also tried not selecting any checkbox but it still won't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get it! Must use same name for the checkboxes like:

> checkbox_name[]

rather than using an array there .. ^_^